# How to control distance parameter in distribute points on faces with the object proximity in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am pretty new to the creation of geometry nodes setup by myself, and I came across a question - how would I control the distance factor in the distribute points on faces, with my proximity object?

[image]

Meaning that I want the distance between my instances to become smaller with further away my proximity object is, just as the scale of instanced objects is already set to decrease. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and in advance sorry if this has a straightforward answer.

[image]

Comment: the simply answer is: you can't because it is a circular input which means: this takes only one input value (not a field as the diamond shape reveals) - but of course you could solve it via a different way. So maybe you wanna change your question to "how can i...?" because you might get the answer you want ;)

Comment: @Chris hi and thank you for your fast reply! sure, then my question is how can i do that - i also wondered about the different shapes of the input sockets in the nodes, thank you for explaining it!